# Google Drive API File query list() method not listing any files(using Python) for download

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, drive

In the code below, I am trying to instantiate the Drive API and would like to query CSV files that have 'AllData' in their name. From the documentation, it looks like I have all the parameters set up properly and the code doesn't generate any error. But the **response** doesn't update the **files** list meaning that **listFiles** doesn't get updated with any filenames/ids/... If anyone faced this issue before, please help. Thanks.

```
# instantiate the service
service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
# print(dir(service))

driveQuery = "(name contains 'AllData' and mimeType = 'text/csv' and trashed = false)"

fieldString = 'files(id, mimeType, parents, name)'

response = service.files().list(
    pageSize=1000,
    q=driveQuery,
    fields=fieldString
).execute()

listFiles = response['files']
nextPageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')

while nextPageToken:
    print("In while....")
    response = service.files().list(
        pageSize=1000,
        q=driveQuery,
        fields=fieldString,
        pageToken=nextPageToken
    ).execute()

    listFiles.extend(response['files'])
    nextPageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your issue, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your issue and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Figured it out somehow, but it was a query issue, I just had to change driveQuery to `driveQuery = " mimeType = 'text/csv' and trashed = false"`. Not sure why name query didn't work though. Maybe queries can be at most two parameters...

Comment: Ok it was because the files didn't match the query for name lolSo dumb of me

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your script, I thought that your search query is correct and `nextPageToken` is required to be included in `fields`. But, from your replying, I understood `name contains 'AllData'` is not required to be used. I couldn't notice it from your question. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I understood that my answer was not useful for your question. So I would like to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I apologize for my poor skill again.